# How to create list of all figures (tables) in Sphinx?

Tags: indexing, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, tableofcontents, myst

In Latex it is possible to create lists of figures and tables:

```
  \listoffigures
  \listoftables
```

=> How to do so in Sphinx for the html output?

I found

```
:ref:`genindex`
```

but nothing like

```
:ref:`genfigureindex`
```

If there is no existing command/extension in Sphinx (?):

a) How to write an extension that uses existing occurrences of the [.. figure](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#figure) ([.. table](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table)) directives in all the pages as a source? (I would prefer a solution that does not require to modify all the existing figures/tables.) Also see related question

[How to loop over all documents and get meta information about existing directives in Sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77264491/how-to-loop-over-all-documents-and-get-meta-information-about-existing-directive)

b) Maybe the search feature or the toctree directive could be used somehow to search/filter for all figures and list them as a an extra page?

Comment: Why is the question tagged "myst"? Are you using both ReStructuredText and Markdown?

Comment: Yes. A solution based on MyST (-parser) would also be fine for me because the most of my content is written in Markdown and I use *.rst only for the main entry point.